# svcutil generated client side WCF service binding code which doesnt compile

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TreeTraversalType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DsLib")]
public enum TreeTraversalType : int
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    PreOrder = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    InOrder = 1,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    PostOrder = 2,
}
```

from service exposing following contract

```
  [OperationContract]
  void PrintTraversePath(TreeTraversalType type);
```

But at client side, it says that `Serialization` does not contain `DataContractAttribute`.

Also, earlier while compiling the service, I got a CLS-non-compliant error for this enum, but later without any related modification, it resolved (must have modified something else which I don't know correlates with this).

My question is, why this compile-error behaviour and what is CLS-compliance. Can't I have enum type in a `Contract` definition of a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums work fine in contracts. Do you have a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (where DataContractAttribute is defined) in your project?

Comment: gosh ! stupid error. hmm i got it working by assembly ref. thanks. i was confused in that whole binding class due to earlier CLS related error. Btw, related to my 2nd question what to take care about CLS compliance in general ?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a reference missing for Runtime.Serialization namespace.

Enums are not the issue. They work well in data contracts.